# Graphical markov chain in javascript

Tags: javascript, graphics, markov-chains

I have a Markov chain that I would like to represent graphically in javascript. I need to represent the nodes, links, and transition probabilities. Perhaps something like one of these two diagrams:

[image]
[image]

Finding a good image library (like Raphael) is not the problem. The problem, for me, is finding a way to make sure the nodes are laid out nicely, with a minimal amount of lines crossing in front of other nodes or lines. Something like the "Lay out diagram" option in OmniGraffle (I'm sure there's a similar feature in Visio).

Is there a JS library that can do this for me, and if not does anyone have any idea how to approach a problem like this? Note that my markov chains are likely to be a lot more complex then the examples above.

Comment: how did the project turn out?

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis i ended up using graphdracula (see my comment to Femi's answer). It worked, but not quite as nice as I had hoped. There were some issues when a node points to itself, or when two nodes form a loop. The placement of the transition probabilities was sometimes unclear which line it belonged to. Still, I couldn't find anything better, so it made do.

Comment: is your code available? I'd be interested in throwing some things at it to see what the chains look like (non-academically related).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might make out okay with one of the directed graph libraries like [D3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) or one of the [directed graph layers on Raphael](http://jasonrowe.com/2010/09/25/force-directed-graph-with-raphael/).

Comment: +1 on using Raphael. 2.0 is also on the way: https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/tree/2.0

Comment: Thanks! I guess it helps to know the right terminology-- googling "force directed graph" helped me find a few other alternatives as well, and graphdracula.net seems to fit my needs. thejit.org is another for those looking for alternatives.

Comment: Hehe. Glad to help provide the right spell to insert into Google.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [mxGraph](http://www.jgraph.com) for this currently. It's not free, but it's a case of you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 0):

[Viz.js](https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js) can be used for this, it is a Javascript port of [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).